# Access to Facebook 3D Photo API/Share functionality for Android apps

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know (maybe we have Facebook Devs here) does Facebook plan to open access to Facebook 3D Photo API/Share functionality for Android apps. They opened access to 3D Posts, but it doesn't allow to change camera FOV (or zoom) settings, so 3D post looks different from 3D photo post made on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

3D Posts API
The API for directly uploading 3D assets is currently under reconstruction. Please stay tuned.
from....
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/3d-posts/3d-posts-api